# Service "elasticsearch" failed to build:Invalid reference format

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

[Project Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZUGC.png)

I was working in a project in which i has to use docker,elastic search etc,i installed all necessary packages and mounted my github repo and i build it , and then this error pops us that Service elastic search failed to build :invalid reference format

Answer (score 1):

The `ELK_VERSION` argument is not passed into the build context.

You have also a warning there mention that for you. Your compose file needs to like this:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: "1.2.3"
```